# How to start a service in Netgear R7000(stock firmware)

Tags: busybox

I am working on Netgear R7000 build system(stock firmware).I want to start a service.I noticed that init is linked to busybox and busybox init does not use run levels.I have written a script in init.d/ but it is not run as there is no symlink corresponding to it as there is no run level in busybox.

How Do I start the service?

Answer (score 0):

Netgear R7000 stock firmware busybox init doesn't follow any run level to start.Rather there is a rc directory in which there is a rc.c file.this is file from where init and pre-init process are initaited.We should make changes in this rc.c main function to obtain the appropriate result.